# iconForFile] returns image with 0 representations

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

My Cocoa application displays file icons for all files in a given folder. I'm using this code to get the icon images:

```
NSImage *icon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:thePath];
```

Once in a while, the returned icon has no (0) image representations, but a size set to 32x32 (default size as the documentation says), other times the correct icon (as shown in Finder) is returned.

I used to check for `nil`, but my app would crash later until I discovered that the image was "empty', so to speak.

When it happens, it is always the same file: a Safari `.webarchive` (the folder has two webarchives, the icon shows for the first one...).

Is there something special about the code above? This is running in a background thread. Could this be the problem? I can't imagine why it should be a problem, as no UI elements are updated from that thread.

Thanks! Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would have to check for some conditions when it is failing i.e. the size == NSZeroSize or the number of image reps is zero, etc... and then have a placeholder image ready for when the returned NSImage is invalid.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm currently doing (checking [[icon representations]count] > 0 (size is 32x32). But I really would like to know why it is failing for the second .webarchive. It returns the correct icon for the first one... Very strange.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be. How did you create the files? Did you use Safari directly, or did you use an Applescript? Another approach would be to create a dictionary of NSImages with the file extension as the key and use this cache if the NSImage is invalid. Does the Finder show the correct icon for this file?

Comment: I used Safari directly to create the files. Sometimes it works just fine and it shows the icon for that second file, other times it doesn't. What's puzzling me is that the call to iconForFile: does not fail (and returns nil), but returns an unusable NSImage.

Comment: And the documentation for this doesn't help. It should clearly state what it returns when it can't find an icon for a file. I would expect nil. I ran some test code that goes through my home directory and the only files that failed to return an icon for were old CodeWarrior *.ppob files.

Comment: When you say failed, did it return nil or an "empty" image? When I try to get an icon for filetype "unknown" it returns the default icon (a blank file) so it looks like that call should always return something.

Answer (score -1):

> This is running in a background thread. Could this be the problem?

The [docs for `NSWorkspace iconForFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528158-iconforfile) state:

> #### Discussion
>
> The returned image has an initial size of 32 pixels by 32 pixels.
>
> It is safe to call this method from any thread of your app.

So the background thread should not be a problem.